# How to get $\sqrt {k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ in the form $\frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

I was wondering if it is possible to get $\sqrt {k} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ in the form $\dfrac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$, and if so, how?

I ask this, because I'm following [this](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.01/john2.html) answer, and I get lost at how they arrive at $\dfrac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** To further clarify what I'm not understanding, please read below:

I don't understand how the author goes from the line:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$

to the line:

$\frac{\sqrt{k^2 + k} + 1}{\sqrt{k + 1}} > \frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

I would really appreciate it if someone could lead me through to that line and explain exactly what is being done on each line.

Thanks again.

Comment: You can't? Take $k=3$, for instance. The first term is $\sqrt{3}+1/2$ and the second is $2$.

Comment: I agree with Mike. What you will get is $\frac{\sqrt{k^2+k}+1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Comment: That's what I thought, I misread the answer, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That answer says

$$\sqrt {k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}= \frac{(\sqrt {k})(\sqrt {k+1}) +1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{\sqrt {k(k+1}) +1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{\sqrt {k^2+\color{red}{k}} +1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\color{blue}{\ge}\frac{\sqrt {k^2} +1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

It's just like saying  $\sqrt{a+b}\ge\sqrt{a}$ for $b\ge0$

> Answer to Edit:

Author want to show that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$$
So you first assume That it is true for $n=k$ that is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}  > \sqrt{k}$$ And then You add $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ to both sides and then show that it is also true for $n=k+1$

Comment: Ok, I get what you've written, but I now don't understand how the author got from the first line (summation >= sqrt(k) + 1/sqrt(k+1)) to the line you've written?

Comment: Well, I understand how to get $\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ in the form $\frac{\sqrt{k^2 + k} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. I also understand that $\frac{\sqrt{k^2 + k} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ is $\geq \frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$, but I don't understand where the $\frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ comes from?

Comment: I get how to get  $\sqrt{k+1}$ from $\frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k + 1}}$, but I don't understand how they've managed to get the $\frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k + 1}}$ in the first place?

Comment: On the left hand side of the inequality, are they replacing the summation up to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ with $\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$?

Comment: It is correct, but I don't think I'm communicating what I don't understand very well. I'm going to edit the question to better explain. Thanks for your help so far though

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now, for some reason I just couldn't get that you are "allowed" to put something in that doesn't strictly follow on from the previous line, but is still mathematically correct, in order to finally get the inequality in the form that you want. Thanks again for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

It cannot hold obviously. When $k=\color{red}1$,  $\sqrt {k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\color{red}{1+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}$, however, $\frac{\sqrt{k^2} + 1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\color{red}{\sqrt2}.$